# Search for functions by type signature

Tags: c++, semantic-mode

Is there a convenient way to search through a C/++ codebase and list all the functions with matching type signatures?

I'm working in a codebase that makes heavy use of function pointers.  Conveniently when they're called, they're matched against a typedef that has a particular argument signature.  If I know the name or symbol of the function being called I can use GTAGS to jump to it, or run semantic searches to find references to it.

However I'd like to find all functions that share a type signature for the purposes of inlining these function pointer calls.  Is there a handy trick for that or am I likely going to need to do a regex search?